# Add Checked in Checkbox if same value in database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, mysqli

I try to add `checked` in my checkbox, if a value in checkbox is same with the value from database:

My database :
    Column = fees_month[] 
    Value = '$row[month]'

```
My Default checkbox :
echo "<th >"."<input type='checkbox' name='fees_month[]' value= '$row[month]' checked='isChecked('$row[month]',$fees_month)' >". $row['month']."</th>";

$q = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM fees WHERE registration_number='$qry[registration_number]'");

while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
    $fees_month = explode(", ", $info['fees_month']);
}

function isChecked($val, $arr) {
    if (in_array($val, $arr)) {
        echo 'checked';
    }
}
```

Comment: @danila, Do you have any suggestion where I`m wrong?

Comment: $q = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT fees_month FROM fees WHERE registration_number='$qry[registration_number]'");
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
{
$fees_month = explode(",", $info['fees_month']);
function isChecked($val, $arr)
{
if(in_array($val,$arr))
{
echo 'checked';
}
}
}                                                                                                                                             echo "<th >"."<input type='checkbox' name='fees_month[]' value= '$row[month]' checked='isChecked($val,$arr);'>". $row['month']."</th>";

Answer (score 1):

```
$selected = array();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db', 'user', 'password');

$query = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT fees_month 
      FROM fees 
     WHERE registration_number = :registration_number
');

$query->bindParam('registration_number', $qry[registration_number]);

while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $selected[] = $row['fees_month'];
}

$checked = in_array($active, $selected) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="fees_month[]" ' . $checked . ' value="' . $active . '"/>';

// example for testing
$active = 1;
$selected = array(1, 10, 20);
$checked = in_array($active, $selected) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';

echo '<input type="checkbox" name="fees_month[]" ' . $checked . ' value="' . $active . '"/>';
```

Comment: Its not working, printing only 'checked' several times without space.

Answer (score 0):

isChecked is not a variable so variable substitution doesn't work here.

You'll have to do something like the following:

```
'" . isChecked(<params>) . "'
```

instead.

Comment: Use the code @danila-ganchar provided. It's my solution without the need for you to do something for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Html checkbox sends value "on" on submitting if checked. If you are directly saving the submitted value, than you should check if the value is on.

For example variable `$checkbox` stores the value that you retrieved from database, you can use something like this :

```
<?php $isChecked = $checkbox == 'on' ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
echo "<input type='checkbox' $isChecked>";
?>
```

Comment: Can you supply more information ? How are you saving the info (if it is checked) ?